# Gain more Results on enhancing the query on one specific Server

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I wrote an Access add-in (VBA) which works perfectly fine on my and other test servers, but on one server I encountered a very strange problem. When I execute the query with the data condition, I get the correct results (which are none). When I add the date condition I get more results than before. These results do not even match with my other conditions. I use the exact same database on both servers.

Here is the Query:

```
    select BE.* from dbo.KHKBuchungserfassung AS BE 
    left join KHKSachkonten AS SSK on BE.KtoSoll = SSK.SaKto and BE.Mandant = SSK.Mandant 
    left join KHKSachkonten AS HSK on BE.KtoHaben = HSK.SaKto and BE.Mandant = HSK.Mandant 
    where ((((BE.KtoSollTyp = 1) or (BE.KtoSollTyp = 2)) and (HSK.Kontenart = 'BF' or HSK.Kontenart = 'BG')) or 
    (((BE.KtoHabentyp = 1) or (BE.KtoHabentyp = 2)) and (SSK.Kontenart = 'BF' or SSK.Kontenart = 'BG'))) 
   and BE.Mandant= 88 and BE.Buchungsdatum>={d '2016-01-01'} AND BE.Buchungsdatum<={d '2016-06-30'}
```

If I execute this on that specific server with `from date < a specific date` ('2016-02-24') it also works perfectly fine (e.g. '2016-01-01' & '2016-06-30'). Any given date higher than this one gives results that violate my first condition... (the one in the parenthesis). I already checked the number of parenthesis. I also rotated the places of the given conditions. In addition to that, I am pretty sure my DBMS would give me an error if there is a problem with my syntax (not sure though).

This is the Result Set:

```
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    sQry = ...
    Set rs = goMandant.oData.rsOpenRecordset(sQry, adOpenStatic)
    Do Until rs.EOF 
    ...
```

I am sorry that I can not provide test data due to juridical reasons, but if you would also select SSK.Kontenart and HSK.Kontenart there would be 'NULL' on both sides which is not at all possible in my first condition...

I would also like to note that this is my first question and if I made any mistakes, I would appreciate it if you told me.

Regards
TK

Comment: Does the SQL run properly from the Access query designer on this server?

Comment: The syntax like `BE.Buchungsdatum>={d '2016-01-01'}` is not valid _Access SQL_ so you must run this as a pass-through query to a database engine - but which?